# AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

When querying my API with `format=json` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Interestingly enough it doesn't happen with the Django Rest Framework API UI. Only when `format=json`.

Here is my list method:

```
def list(self, request):
    queryset = dataset_models.DataSet.objects.all()
    serializer = serializers.DataSetListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And my serializer:

```
class DataSetListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = dataset_models.DataSet
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.7.example1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  187.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v0/a-cb4be7e8/p/example.com/dataset/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What gives?

Comment: What is the *full* traceback? You probably shouldn't use the name `list` for your function as that masks the built-in type. The object in your exception is the actual `list` *type*, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my thoughts exactly but according to the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#api-guide) `list` is the expected method for that request. I'm overriding `list` in my case. Traceback added.

Comment: Right; as a method is namespaced that should be okay.

Comment: That's an awfully short traceback with no visible correlation whatsoever with the exception, though.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `many=True` it serializes several objects and puts them in a list. As the `JSONResponse` class expects to be passed a dict (unless also passed `safe=False`), I'm guessing your `Response` class does as well.

Comment: I took another look at the `Response` class. It's just a subclass of `SimpleTemplateResponse`. However, I did notice in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses#response()) that the `content_type` parameter is supposed to be set automatically if properly determined by content negotiation. In other words, something in the content negotiation seems to be off because if i pass the `content_type` it works.

Comment: As I recall you can perfectly pass lists to the response-class in DRF.

Comment: It does seem you're supposed to be able to. A simple way to test whether the list being passed to `Response` is the list being complained about in the exception would be to make it a dict and see what happens.  Eg. `Response(dict(enumerate(serializer.data)))`

Comment: @RossRidge Passing a dict works fine. Something like `Response({'data': serializer.data})`.

Comment: Have you had any luck trying to get a full traceback? Done the obvious like set `DEBUG=True` in you Django settings? I think we'll need the full traceback to figure out why it doesn't work with lists.

Comment: @RossRidge I did paste the full traceback above and debug is set to True. The message is not all that useful.